# Implementing basic animations with tvOS

Tags: swift, uiview, tvos, animatewithduration

I'm hoping someone may be able to help me understand why my tvOS animations are not running.

In my code I have a function like this:

```
func testAnimation() {
    clockLabel.alpha = 0.0
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: {
        self.clockLabel.alpha = 1.0
    })
}
```

I am calling `testAnimation()` from within my `viewDidLoad()`, but no animation ever seems to happen.

I've tested with a few different types of animations, from things like position to opacity, but it seems that no animation ever actually runs in the Simulator.

At this time, my app does not have a **focus**. All I'm trying to do is load a blank `UIView` with a label in the middle that fades in.

Comment: Please share your code in viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to animate your `UILabel` before it has been displayed. Move your animation from `viewDidLoad()` to `viewDidAppear()`.

Comment: Yup.  That fixed it for me.  Strange that it behaves differently on an iOS app, but perhaps that's cause for concern anyway.  Thank you, though, this has resolved my issue!

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm this behaviour as this happens for me as well. What I did was setting a delay of 0.1 (afterDelay:), and it is "good enough"

On the other hand, what DID actually work was setting a transform for my views. E.g. (objc though):

```
    CGAffineTransform scaleTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5,0.5);
         [UIView animateWithDuration: 0.5 animations:^{
         _myView.transform = scaleTransform;
    } completion: nil]
```

Maybe it's a bug in tvOS

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this. What happens if it takes the system longer than `0.1` to present the view after loading it?

Answer (score 0):

Try using UIView Animation, like this (Swift):

```
clockLabel.alpha = 0
  UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0, options: .Linear, animations: {
    self.clockLabel.alpha = 1.0

  }, completion: { finished in
    // you may add some code here to make another action right after the animation end, or just delete this comment :)
  })
```

This works on our side.